# How to read the generated ID at Runtime Automate Testing with VS2010 Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, automation

I Created a **Coded UI** Test , then recorded the site which creates a submission Id every time i run the Automation Test.

My Issue:-

1. How to read the Id generated at runtime.
2. How to Store this Id in xml or some csv for future test use.

FYI information my site is sharepoint web portal site , i do not have TFS server running and neither i want to use TEST Manager.

What ever i want to do is in the Test Project Itself and the XMl file.

Looking forward to get answered for 1 and 2 issues.

THanks,
Mukesh

Comment: You may want to look at this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsautotest/threads

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Visual Studio IDE, this folder is created directly under the solution folder; if you are not using the Visual Studio IDE, the TestResults folder is created under the current folder.

Every time that you start a test run, Visual Studio creates, under the TestResults folder, a set of folders to be used exclusively for that test run. In the example shown in the following illustration, the first folder under TestResults is "@ ". This is the pattern used to name each of these folders.